# What do you call this origami thing that kind of looks like a windmill?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

What do you call these toy "windmills" made from folded paper?

[image]

Comment: Close voters and down voters: how is this a bad question? We have a tag for asking the word for something in an image.

Comment: I didn’t realise there was a tag for that, but now I can’t change my vote on the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called ‘pinwheels’, and can also be made out of plastic.

Comment: In the UK they're just called windmills, toy or paper windmills.